# How can I take a variable from an if statement in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, variables

this might be a rather stupid question, but im new to this codeing thing. I was wondering if you can take a variable from an if statement and use it outside the if statement as I showed in this exemple down here:

```
bool ex = true;
if (ex == true)
{
    int num = 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

I already tried to declare the variable before the if statement but i gave me an error:[image]

Comment: Your error suggests you just had a syntax error you needed to fix. `int num = 0;` outside your `if block` and then `num = 10` inside of it. Previously the error suggests that you had `int num = 0;` inside your if block as well, which is wrong.

Comment: There is something you should look into called "scopes". here is a little link that should explain the basics of this -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Comment: You can't - you have to declare `num` outside of the `if` scope to use it outside of the `if`. That error would indicate that you have _another_ `num` declared somewhere else.

Comment: You can just look up the error, it tells you how to resolve your issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a variable before if statement and then you can bind a new value to that variable inside if statement and use it outside if statement wherever you required inside your function scope.

```
    bool ex = true;
    int num = 0;
    if (ex == true)
    {
        num = 10;

    }
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Note that i have not used int keyword again while binding value to num variable in if statement as we have defined it already outside of the loop otherwise it will give an error like -> A local variable named 'num' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'num'.

Comment: While not really part of the discussion of variable scope, consider the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for a simple, inline way to represent the same logic (assuming `bool ex` was already set): `int num = ex ? 10 : 0;`

Comment: I could have posted that as an answer but i think you have not read the question carefully that he was said that he is a beginner so i have written full code block for better understanding.

Comment: I agree it's not an answer; I didn't post it as one.  =)  The question as asked is really about variable scoping.  Since OP is a beginner (and others finding this might be too), I thought it useful to introduce this concept - it's just a clean way to achieve the same code used in the example, as it avoids the scope concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The conceptual thing this example teaches is that of *local variable scopes*.

The body of a method (e.g., `Main`) is surrounded by `{` and `}` characters. This indicates that any variables you *declare* between these braces can only be written or read to from within the same braces. We call this a "scope". And this applies to most cases of `{` and `}` characters, nested within the method.

So in your case:

```
static void Main()
{                               // beginning of method scope
    bool ex = true;
    if (ex == true)
    {                           // beginning of if statement scope
        int num = 10;
    }                           // end of if statement scope
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}                               // end of method scope
```

There are two scopes: a scope for the `Main` method, and a scope within that first scope just for the code inside the `{` and `}` after the `if`.

- `ex` is declared (`bool ex`) in the outer scope, so you can use it anywhere in the method, including within the inner scope.
- `num` is declared (`int num`) in the inner scope, so you can only use it within the inner scope, not the outer scope.

To fix this, you can *declare* a variable, then later assign a value to it. So our next shot would be:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool ex = true;
    int num;              // declare the variable here
    if (ex == true)
    {
        num = 10;         // assign the variable here
    }
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

This is closer, but we still get an error, this time:

> CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'num'

That's because of another rule: in order to use a local variable, the compiler has to be able to know that the variable has always been assigned a value before it's used. In this case, what would happen if `ex` was `false`? Then we would declare `num`, but never give it a value, because the program wouldn't enter into the `if` scope.

The solution is to give `num` a value, either at the same time we declare it...

```
static void Main()
{
    bool ex = true;
    int num = 5;          // declare and assign the variable here
    if (ex == true)
    {
        num = 10;         // re-assign the variable here
    }
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

...or in an `else` statement.

```
static void Main()
{
    bool ex = true;
    int num;              // declare the variable here
    if (ex == true)
    {
        num = 10;         // assign the variable here if ex is true
    }
    else
    {
        num = 5;          // assign the variable here if ex is false
    }
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

In the first case, `num` is given a value as soon as we declare it, so even if we don't enter the `if` block, `num` will have a value when we reach `Console.WriteLine`.

In the second case, the compiler knows that when you chain `if` and `else` together, the program is going to go into exactly **one** of the two. Thus, if we ensure both paths set `num`, then it will also be guaranteed to have a value once we reach `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Above the if statement write, "
`int num;`
"
and then inside the if statement write, "
`num = 10;`
"

You don't have to initialize a variable when you declare it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen oops thanks

Comment: We can infer from the question that the outermost scope is that of a method, not a class. So `var num` or `int num` is sufficient. (But C# does assume private if you don't specify it for a field.)